# How would i set two coordinates for two different words on screen?

Tags: c++

I want to set two different coordinates for two words.
Im using `COORD pos = {20,20}` for one word
 i tried using

```
COORD position = {10,10}
SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, pos)
cout << "word A" << endl
SetConsoleCursorPosition(screen, position)  
cout << "word B" << endl
```

for the other but no luck

Comment: What exactly happens?
Also... newlines and semi-colons please.

Comment: Did you get the standard handle for the screen variable?

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to get the standard output handle.

```
    HANDLE screen = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
```